# Relation models with ODE and continuous Markov chains.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, self-learning, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ be a stochastic process with state space $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ (that is, $I$ is the set of values that each $X_t$ may take) and call $c(t)=(P(X_t=1),\ldots,P(X_t=n))$.

Suppose the following model: $c'(t)=c(t)Q$, where $Q$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that: $Q_{ii}\leq 0$, $Q_{ij}\geq0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n Q_{ij}=0$ for all $i$.

I would like to know if $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a Markov chain in continuous time.

**Intuition**: I think this should be true: we have, for a very small $h$, $$\frac{P(X_{t+h}=j)-P(X_t=j)}{h}\approx \frac{d}{dt}P(X_t=j)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_t=i)\,Q_{ij}\;\;\Rightarrow$$
$$P(X_{t+h}=j)\approx\sum_{i\neq j}P(X_t=i)(h\,Q_{ij})+(1+h\,Q_{jj})P(X_t=j).$$
So, if we look the process at $h$ units of time, $X_{t+h}$ depends on the past only from $X_t$, that is, we have a discrete Markov chain.

**Question**: I would like a formal proof of $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ being a Markov chain in continuous time.

Comment: There exists some Markov process $(Y_t)$ such that, for each $t$, the distributions of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ coincide -- but there is no reason why $(X_t)$ itself should be a Markov process. Consider for example $$c(t)=\begin{pmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{pmatrix}\qquad Q=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ then $c(t)Q=0$ hence indeed $c'(t)=c(t)Q$ but we only know that every $X_t$ is uniform on $\{1,2\}$, which is definitely not enough to conclude that $(X_t)$ is a Markov process.

Comment: @Did Ok, I understand. And as a curiosity, why does there exist that process $(Y_t)$?

Comment: Because every generator $Q$ (in your context, this is a matrix with nonnegative off-diagonal entries, whose rows sum to zero) yields a Markov semi-group $(P_t)$ defined by $P_t=e^{tQ}$.